# Validate authentication code with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to have users log in with a 6 digit code they get from an Authentication app.
So far I figured out how to check wether the code is the same in the app and online. 
It says "454 343" in the Google Authentication app, and by going to https://authenticatorapi.com/validate.aspx?Pin=454343&SecretCode=1234 
I will get a response saying either True or False.
**How exactly do I take that "True" or "False" and set it as a variable in JS?**

Comment: FYI the server is denying all requests, and there is no documentation for this API; I would find a different one

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(async () => {
    const
        url = 'https://authenticatorapi.com/validate.aspx?Pin=454343&SecretCode=1234',
        response = await fetch(url),
        answer = await response.text() === 'True';

    console.log(answer);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is sending a HTTP request to that url which tells you if the code is correct.

Previously, you would use `XMLHttpRequest` but that is becoming somewhat dated.

Instead, I recommend using the `fetch` API:

```js
(async () => {
    var response = await fetch("https://authenticatorapi.com/validate.aspx?Pin=454343&SecretCode=1234");
    console.log(response.text()); // should print out "True" or "False"
})();
```

For more information, check out

Note that the code is inside an `async function` because `fetch()` is asynchronous

Comment: ha I like the clean code! i had to go and fine out what those parenthesis were for and learned what an IFFE was.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I would do it,

```
var test = new Promise (resolve => {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          resolve(xhttp.responseText)
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://authenticatorapi.com/validate.aspx?Pin=454343&SecretCode=1234", false);
    xhttp.send();
})

test.then(result => {
  console.log(result)
  // expected result is boolean
})
```